# entering text into an editbox; delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to enter characters into an edit box by way of the user clicking buttons on a Delphi form. `Button1`, for example, adds to the contents of the edit box the character `'1'`; `Button2` adds the character `'2'`, etc.

Here is the relevant code in the event handler for each button - to take `Button1` adding `1` as an example:

```
Edit1.text := Edit1.Text + '1';
```

The problem is that clicking on some buttons ensures the a number appears in the edit box while clicking on others does not, ie no number appears.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong, and explain what the problem is? I'm new to all this.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing the problem in action. How many characters can you add before they stop appearing? Is there a pattern to the behavior? Are you taking into account that the `TEdit` does not automatically scroll horizontally if you add more characters than it can display?

Comment: Thanks. The problem is not that the edit box does fails to scroll; the data entered into the editbox fits comfortably within the box.

Comment: Yes I am indeed using  Tedit.  The aim is to enter a sequence of chars without using the keyboard. That is, the user clicks on the buttons referred to in the first message.

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of what you're attempting to do? I'm not sure what your problem is. Could it be that you have created multiple buttons, and event handlers in the code, but have not yet linked the button's `OnClick` event to its appropriate event handler yet?

Comment: The buttons are contained on a Tpanel, which itself occupies the same delphi form as the editbox.  I have not made use of a tmemo.

Comment: Sorry if all this is a bit confusing.  The buttons all have event handlers of the form listed in the initial message. The funny this is this: if I simply insert a shomessage(editbox1) into the event handler code:

Comment: Edit1.text := Edit1.Text + '1';

Comment: after the edit1.text:=edit1.text+'1' (or whatever the char is) then the button works fine from then on in that the editbox does display the character in question.

Answer (score 1):

Add this event handler to your form:

```
procedure TForm1.NumberButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text := Edit1.Text + (Sender as TButton).Caption;
end;
```

Using the Object Inspector's Events tab, set the OnClick handler of all the buttons on the panel to the above event handler.

This works perfectly in Delphi 10.1 Berlin and Delphi 2007. If it doesn't work for you, then you have something else happening and will need to post enough code for us to use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If this doesn't work, then you must not be using Delphi :-)

Comment: Lol! Thanks for the advice. I would never actually have thought of that. Somehow or other I do seem to have fixed the problem. I'm still learning how to think like a programmer and have a long way to go! Thanks again.